# Django filter by field named 'id' in JSONField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Django application and PostgreSQL database. 
My problem is that I cannot filter by field named 'id' in JSONField.

My model looks like that:

```
class SnapshotAuditing(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I populate it like that:

```
snapshot = SnapshotAuditing(
    data={
        'id': student.id,
        'some_value': some_value,
    }
)
snapshot.save()
```

Than I want to perform the following select request:

```
price_change = SnapshotAuditing.objects.filter(
    data__id=student.id
).order_by('created').first()
```

But I get this error:

```
    bl/transfers.py:98: in get_coefficient_and_hours_unused
    data__id=student.id
../env2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py:85: in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
../env2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:784: in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
../env2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:802: in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
../env2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1250: in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
../env2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1276: in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
../env2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1210: in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
../env2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1102: in build_lookup
    lhs = self.try_transform(lhs, name, lookups)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x1182f6dd0>, lhs = Col(student_snapshotauditing, student.SnapshotAuditing.data), name = 'id', rest_of_lookups = ['id']

    def try_transform(self, lhs, name, rest_of_lookups):
        """
            Helper method for build_lookup. Tries to fetch and initialize
            a transform for name parameter from lhs.
            """
        transform_class = lhs.get_transform(name)
        if transform_class:
            return transform_class(lhs)
        else:
            raise FieldError(
                "Unsupported lookup '%s' for %s or join on the field not "
                "permitted." %
>               (name, lhs.output_field.__class__.__name__))
E           FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'id' for JSONField or join on the field not permitted.

../env2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1120: FieldError
```

Can you help with it, please?

Comment: i tested your code replace student.id with number and all works fine, need more details. Try to show full error.

Comment: @BearBrown i've updated question with full error

Comment: @pngnviko in the code of the error you show is absent link to your code.

Comment: @BearBrown stackoverflow is deleting some lines if they are supposed to be insecure.

Comment: ok is the function name where the error raised is`get_coefficient_and_hours_unused` ? if so please put full code of the function.

Comment: @BearBrown the error was raised here in this query `SnapshotAuditing.objects.filter(data__id=student.id).order_by('created').first()`

Comment: i understand it but this code should work. Only if your redefine some variable in the function can be error, i think so.

Comment: @BearBrown thank you very much for you help! You are right, all this code is valid. The problem was in those lines in my project: `from jsonfield.fields import JSONField; from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField as DjangoJSONField`. So... as you can see, I didn't notice that `SnapshotAuditing ` model is using `jsonfield.fields.JSONField `.

Comment: glad to help you!